# How to clear undefined variable Laravel 9.48.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

```
public function student(){
   $users=DB::select('select * from details');
   return view('welcome',['users'->$users]);
}

@foreach ($users as $user)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->email}}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->status}}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->subject}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: iv selected a data from db $users=DB::select('select * from details'); I'v used every method like using dd, compact, etc... but i get the same error undefined variable $users

Comment: what exactly are you asking?? what is the issue??

Comment: ['users'=>$users]

Comment: for view you need to either use `['users' => $users]` or `compact('users')`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use raw sql query instead you can do it like this

```
    public function student()
    {
        $users=Details::all();
        return view('welcome',compact('users'));
    }
```

or like this

```
    public function student()
    {
        $users = DB::table('details')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();
        return view('welcome', compact('users'));
    }
```

and then in your blade you could get it like this

```
                @isset($users)
                    @foreach ($users as $user)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->status }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->subject }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @endisset
```

Comment: please update your question and add error code or screenshot of the error so we can find the error easily

Comment: I'v updated by uploading image please help me to clear my error

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGiYP.png  error

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4FO5.png  controller

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HznYL.png  view

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJRSc.png  route

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X16C.png  error line

Comment: the problem is that your are using the first route "/" not the "/welcome" route. and in your insertform method you are not sending the $users

Comment: I've updated my answer please check the blade